# Vampire movie where they embrace being a vampire

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

It was a vampire movie that I started watching with my dad in the late nineties on HBO; he turned it off because it was too intense for me.  I remember it was about vampires being bad and embracing being a vampire.  I remember a shoe store scene where they kill everyone.  I think the main character is a female. And it possibly was made in the '80s or early '90s.  It took place in modern times.  Lots of nudity and violence.

Comment: This is quite a generic and brief description. Can you remember anything else at all that happens in the film? If so please [edit] your question to include extra details.

Comment: Was it a relatively monochrome film? *The Addiction* from 1995 ticks off some of the boxes.